# Anchor tags are not working in Safari browser

Tags: html

In my project all my anchor tags are working perfectly in IE and Chrome but none of them are not working in Safari browser.

below is my tag.

```
<a id="btnNewCompany" href="#" onclick="btnNewCompany_OnClick()"
 runat="server"> Add Company </a>
```

From the above i am calling the btnNewCompany_ OnClick() javascript.

```
function btnNewCompany_OnClick() {    
    $get('btnEdit').click(); -----> onserverclick event
        }
```

Can ay one please help me why Anchors are not working in Safari?

Comment: Have you tried using the script debugger and setting a breakpoint in the btnNewCompany_OnClick() function?

Comment: Yes. btnNewCompany_OnClick() function not calling.

Comment: @Indra: Did you try setting the handler from JavaScript and not from the `onclick=` attribute?

Comment: If you add `alert('clicked');` in the function do you get the alert in Safari?

Comment: Yes Shadow. It's showing alert box.

Answer (score 0):

I think in asp.net webforms onclick will look for that method in the server side code, try changing it to OnClientClick instead

Answer (score 0):

If @thebiffboff isn't right, try declaring it like this:

```
btnNewCompany_OnClick = function() {

}
```